# "Process exited with error code 1" This is the error message is displayed with code error : 1 when I run my below script

Tags: angularjs, protractor

> Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page:
>   "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.
>   This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because
>   your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with
>   Protractor's bootstrapping. See http://git.io/v4gXM for details

I am using page object model in the below code. but If I use a normal code it works fine. can you tell me where to correct this code. As this is a confidential project I cannot present my current url
config file:

```
exports.config={
directConnect: true,
framework: 'jasmine',
capabilities:
{
'browserName' : 'chrome'

    },

    specs: ['specs.js'],

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,

}
```

Page object model

```
var CAPTNLoginpage = function(){
var NameInput = element(by.id('userNameInput'));
var PasswordInput = element(by.id('passwordInput'));
var Submit = element(by.id('submitButton'));

this.get=function(){

    browser.get('https://xxxxxxxx/', 25000);
    browser.ignoreSyncronization=true;
    browser.driver.sleep(10000);
    var title = browser.getTitle();
    console.log(title);
};

this.setName = function(name){
    NameInput.sendKeys(name);
};

this.setPassword = function(password){
    PasswordInput.sendKeys(password);
};

this.loginsubmit=function(){
    Submit.click();
};
};

module.exports = new CAPTNLoginpage();

specs
var CAPTNLogin = require('./CAPTNLoginpage');
describe('CAPTN Login Page', function(){

it('Should login into CAPTN',function(){

    CAPTNLogin.get();

    CAPTNLogin.setName('xxxxxxxxxxx');
    CAPTNLogin.setPassword('5196qL25196qL2');
    CAPTNLogin.loginsubmit();

});
});
```

If I use a normal procedure then It works fine
Specs without Page object model

```
describe('Protractor Demo App', () => {

it('should have title', () =>  {
    browser.get('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/');
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.driver.sleep(30000);
    var a = browser.getTitle();
    console.log(a);
    element(by.id('userNameInput')).sendKeys('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    element(by.id('passwordInput')).sendKeys('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    element(by.id('submitButton')).click();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This particular issue can occur if you are running an old version of Chrome driver. The fix is simple, upgrade your chrome driver to the latest version (2.35 at time of writing this).  Here is a sample of a command to update your chrome driver:

```
node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.35 --standalone false --gecko false
```

(this is if you have protractor installed local to your project).

If you aren't sure where protractor is installed (locally or globally) on your machine, and the above doesn't work, try it directly like this:

```
webdriver-manager update --versions.chrome 2.35 --standalone false --gecko false
```

if that doesn't work, then first install the webdriver manager (`npm install -g webdriver-manager`).

If your issue is simply that your driver was out of date, then this should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. And the problem is in this line:

```
var title = browser.getTitle();
```

It is trying to sync with the page object but we're telling it to store the title right away which is causing this problem. In my opinion, the error itself is kinda misleading. I had the same line of code too. I removed it and it worked fine.

Please remove this line from here and try again.

If you do want the title, please write another function for this in your page object. Something like:

```
this.getBrowserTitle = function() {
var title = browser.getTitle();
return title;    
};
```

Hope this helps. Do let me know if this fixes your issue. POM is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need to kill chromedriver process to get rid of this error.

```
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~/openfield-cloud/nightwatch$ npx nightwatch --test ./tests/widgets/banner.test.js --testcase "Hide Row Label in Banner Widget" 
   Error: ChromeDriver process exited with code: 1
   [1663729485.869][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Address already in use (98)

       at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
 [1663729485.869][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Address already in use (98)

vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~/openfield-cloud/nightwatch$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
14354 pts/7    00:00:00 chromedriver
14416 pts/7    00:00:01 chrome <defunct>
14854 pts/7    00:00:00 npm exec serve
14878 pts/7    00:00:00 sh
14879 pts/7    00:00:00 node
15134 pts/7    00:00:00 ps
23260 pts/7    00:00:00 bash
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~/openfield-cloud/nightwatch$ kill -9 14354
vikaspiprade@AUMEL-P7750-VP:~/openfield-cloud/nightwatch$
```